# Data Validation using Express and React

Tags: reactjs, express

I am fairly new to react and express and I am using vanilla react i.e. using it as a html file loading reactjs from CDN:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
```

I have created sign up and login form with reactjs:

```html
<script type="text/babel">
  class SignUpForm extends React.Component { render() { return(

  <div id="signup">
    <form method="post" action="/signup/">
      <div class="form-group">

        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="email" className="form-control" required placeholder="Email" id="Email" name="userid" onChange={this.handleChange} autofocus />

        <p id="ERR_EMAIL"></p>

        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" className="form-control" required placeholder="password" id="Password" name="password" minLength="8" maxlength="16" onChange={this.handleChange} />

        <p id="ERR_PASSWORD"></p>

        <label>Confirm Password:</label>
        <input type="password" className="form-control" required placeholder="password" id="Conpassword" minLength="8" maxlength="16" onBlur={this.handleComp} />
      </div>

      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default btn-md theme" id="loginbtn" onClick={this.handleClick}>Sign Up</button>

    </form>
    <div class="alert-warning" id="ERR_MSG">{this.state.error}</div>

    <a href="#" onClick={this.handleLinkClick}>Already a member login</a>
  </div>); } }

</script>
```

and I am performing server side validation in express:

```js
app.post('/signup/', function(req, res) {

      req.body.username;
      req.body.password

      /* some valdiation code*/


      /*....*/

      //how do I send output back to html page where I am using react to render component


    }
```

My question is how do I pass the error messages back to client in case there is error in the data submitted by the client

Answer (score 3):

For example: 
Server-side:

```
router.post('/user', (req, res, next) => {
    login = req.body.login;
    password = req.body.password;
....//your validation logic

    if (isDataInvalid) {
        res.json({ statusCode: 400, message: "data is invalid" });
       } else {
        res.json({ statusCode: 200 });
       }
    });
```

Client-side:

```
login (login, password)  {
   return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch (`http://yourserver.com/user`, {
        method: "post",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type" : "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({login: login, password: password})
    }).then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => resolve(response))
    .catch(error => { console.log(error); reject(error);});
   })
}
```

And

```
this.login(login, password).then(response => {
   if (response.statusCode === 400) alert (response.message);
});
```

Comment: you are still using javascript to send data to the server what if javascript is disabled?

Comment: You also can't use react in your app, if javascript is disabled. I think almost all modern web apps made assuming, that js is enabled

Comment: What I am saying is if I just remove the client side login code data can still be sent through form to the server so my question how do I validate that data and send back response to the client

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you have architected your app.

If your backend is a JSON API then you can send it back as JSON, i.e.

```
return res.status(422).json({errors: {
   email: 'Invalid email address provided', 
   password: 'Invalid password'
}});
```

If your app is rendered on the server-side then include the errors inside of the HTML template that you're sending back.